# How to use third party shared library (.so) and provided (.jar) wrapper in Android app using Android Studio 2.1?

Tags: java, android, linux, android-studio, android-ndk

I have to use some native library in my android app.

I didn't build this library. It is open source available library. I am using Android Studio 2.1.

So I have two things:

**1. Source for Linux: gcc x86/x64 (.a, .h) files**

**2. Wrapper for Linux: one library.so file and one library.jar file**

What I want to achieve is to use library.so file and library.jar file to consume the library in my Android app.

1) Is it possible?

2) If it is possible then how to do this?

3) If it is not possible then I have only option to do something with NDK?

4) If I have only option to use NDK then how to achieve my goal using NDK?

Note: I am new to Android and NDK I don't know anything please correct me and redirect me to a right path. Please use basic terms so that I can understand easily. Thank you :)

Comment: .a aren't source files but compiled binaries. You need to recompile the real sources for Android using the NDK. However we can't help you much without the details on the library you're trying to use.

Comment: @ph0b
The team of that library only provides .h and .a files in the name of source. So it means the source is incomplete?

Comment: Yes, and you need these sources to be recompiled for Android platforms and architectures, by the team or yourself if you can get the sources.

Comment: @ph0b Thank you so much : )

Comment: @ph0b Kindly put your above both comments as the answer I'll accept as right answer because it is actually the right answer.